# In React Native, How to have multiple multiline textinputs that don't hide behind the keyboard in one scrollable form?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Has anyone been able to achieve the problem mentioned in the title? I've spent days, and still fail to make a form with multiple multiline textinputs.

Here's how the problem looks like:

[image]

The text goes behind the keyboard instead of scrolling down.

I tried this package:

https://github.com/baijunjie/react-native-input-scroll-view

But it just doesn't work at all, text goes behind the keyboard and it doesn't scroll with the keyboard. 1/10 times I do see it working, it scrolls to the right point and above the keyboard, but most of the time the text goes behind the keyboard.

I also tried the following package, which works nicely with single-line inputs, but as described in issues below it fails to work with multi-line inputs with the latest versions of react-native.

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/227

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/pull/251

I've had to resort to react native's `keyboardavoidingview` , which works in normal cases, but not in a scorllview.

Let me know if you have any suggestions. All I'm trying to achieve is have a scrollable form, with multiple multi-line text inputs. Creative solutions are also welcome!